# How to Adjust Stroke/Outline Size of iOS Fonts using the UISlider (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uislider, stroke

I am trying to make an app that has the functionality of dynamically changing the stroke/outline size of iOS fonts using the UISlider. I know how to change the font size and color with a UISlider but I haven't found any useful answers in StackOverflow for stroke size. I see people use CGContextStrokePath but I don't know how I would connect that to my UISlider. So now I am using AttributedText that is almost working but just is not working correctly. When I use the slider, the foreground text goes clear. Does anyone know how to fix that so the foreground color stays the same? And does anyone know a better way to change the stroke or outline of text that connects to a UISlider?

What I have kind of works. But again, the foreground text goes clear.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *strokeSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textToChange;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *showStrokeLabel;

-(IBAction)setValueForStroke:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slide = (UISlider *) sender;
    float number = [slide value];
    int sizeValue = (int)(number * 8);
    NSString *numbers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sizeValue];
    self.showStrokeLabel.text = numbers;

    self.textToChange.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.textToChange.text attributes:@{ NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @(self.strokeSlider.value*-6) }];

}
```

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV4sI.png)

Any help would be much appreciated. Feel free to ask me any questions if I need to clarify anything. Thanks.

Comment: so you simply want to modify width based on slider value? SHow us what u tried

Comment: @Mr.T I updated my question with the code I am stuck on.

Comment: i didnt understand what u r trying to do. Are you changind the label font size based on slider ?

Comment: @Mr.T I added a screenshot to show what I am doing. Does that make more sense?